# The URI prefix is not recognized OnDownloadStringCompleted

Tags: c#, web-services, ihttphandler

I've got a problem with simply method whch gets string from asp.net 4 ashx. I'm running below methods from silverlight application which is being hosted by this asp.net application.

```
private void LoadPlugins()
{
    var serviceAddress = _baseAddress
        + "PluginsService.ashx?"
        + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(serviceAddress));
}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(
    object sender,
    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var plugins = e.Result.Split(
        new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var plugin in plugins)
    {
        AddXap(_baseAddress + plugin);
    }
}
```

PluginsService.ashx.cs:

```
namespace MefPlugins.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PluginsService
    /// </summary>
    public class PluginsService : IHttpHandler
    {
        private const string PluginsFolderName = "Plugins/";

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //var pluginFolder = new DirectoryInfo(
            //    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
            //    PluginsFolderName));
            //var response = new StringBuilder();

            //if (pluginFolder.Exists)
            //{
            //    foreach (var xap in pluginFolder.GetFiles("*.xap"))
            //    {
            //        response.AppendLine(
            //            PluginsFolderName + xap.Name);
            //    }
            //}

            var response = new StringBuilder();
            response.Append("test");
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(response);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
  StackTrace:
       w System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
       w System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
       w MefPlugins.MainPage.client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       w System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       w System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
       InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
            Message=The URI prefix is not recognized.
            StackTrace:
                 w System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
                 w System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
                 w System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri address, Object userToken)
            InnerException:

Where could be a bug? this is an example from http://www.galasoft.ch/sl4u/code/chapter20/20.02-Mef/MefPlugins.zip

Comment: You knew I would ask this... What is the URI prefix? What does `_baseAddress` look like?

Comment: And while you are at it. What is (if anything) in the "Check InnerException for exception details"

Comment: serviceAddress is "file:////PluginsService.ashx?634485607882333736"

Comment: {System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   w System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   w System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   w System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri address, Object userToken)
   --- Koniec śladu stosu wyjątków wewnętrznych ---}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error lies in which project is startup object selected as your startup project.

When your startup project is the **MefPlugins** projec (a Silverlight Project)t, the project settings indicate that a web page should be dynamically created to host your Silverlight application (right click on project, select Properties and go to the Debug tab).

The problem you runing into has to do with the location that is used as a prefix for the `PluginsService.ashx` file. The `_baseAddress` is set by in the main page constructor by the following code:

```
var xapUri = App.Current.Host.Source;
_baseAddress = xapUri.AbsoluteUri
                     .Substring(0, xapUri.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(xapUri.AbsolutePath)) 
               + "/";
```

This means that the Uri of the xap file is used to determine the base uri. Now, as the project is using a dynamically generated container page - which is located on your hard drive and started from there - the above code takes the filesystem root is the `_baseAddress`. Obviously, the code will not find the `PluginsService.ashx` page, as it is not there.

Additionally, an `.ashx` file needs some form of http listener that routes the request from a port to your `.ashx` page. The listener can be a web server like IIS or the development web server, or some listener you implemented yourself.

To solve the problem make the **MefPlugins.Web** project your startup project and set `MefPluginsTestPage.aspx` as your startup page. Now `_baseAddress` should be something simlilar to `http://localhost:6584/`.

When this base address is now used to find the `PluginsService.ashx` page, it will result in a correct URI for the resource (`http://localhost:6584/PluginsService.ashx` in our case).

In general `.ashx` files are extensions to a web service (IIS, debug web server, or even some own implementation) they are **not** part of the silverlight client.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that the Uri you're passing to `DownloadStringAsync` is a relative Uri. That is: "file://PluginsService.ashx" is relative to the current directory. You probably want an absolute Uri (i.e. fully-qualified path name) as in "file://C:\projects\test\PluginsService.ashx".

Comment: Problem lies in the base URI of the xap file and this depends on which solution is the startup project. See my answer.